# How to reserve the right space for bigger headlines and footlines?

Tags: header-footer, plain-tex

I set the headline and footline size to 2cm and reduced the \vsize by 4cm. But the footer does not fit the page.

```
\pdfpagewidth=10cm
\pdfpageheight=10cm
\hsize=\pdfpagewidth
\vsize=\pdfpageheight \advance\vsize by -4cm
\advance\hoffset by -1in
\advance\voffset by -1in
\def\makeheadline{\vbox to 2cm{\hbox{headline 1}\hbox{headline 2}\hbox{headline 3}\vss}\nointerlineskip}
\def\makefootline{\vbox to 2cm{\vss\hbox{footline 1}\hbox{footline 2}\hbox{footline 3}}\nointerlineskip}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam
et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam
et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\bye
```

> [image: footer]

Is there any hidden space I have to reduce?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I reduced the vsize by the size needed for header and footer. But the footer still does not fit the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: question]

You can debug what is going on by adding `\tracingoutput=1` and looking in the log file (or additionally add `\tracingonline=1` to see it in output directly). With the code in [the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/528689/2), this gives (with `\showboxdepth=1` to suppress further levels of output):

```
Completed box being shipped out [1]
\vbox(287.47198+0.0)x284.52756
.\vbox(56.9055+0.0)x44.44453, glue set 25.96106fil []
.\vbox(170.71654+1.94444)x284.52756, glue set 4.71654 []
.\glue(\lineskip) 1.0
.\vbox(56.9055+0.0)x41.11122, glue set 25.96106fil []
```

and

```
Completed box being shipped out [2]
\vbox(285.52754+0.0)x284.52756
.\vbox(56.9055+0.0)x44.44453, glue set 25.96106fil []
.\vbox(170.71654+0.0)x284.52756, glue set 98.7721fill []
.\glue(\lineskip) 1.0
.\vbox(56.9055+0.0)x41.11122, glue set 25.96106fil []
```

for the two pages respectively. So in each case you see:

- The header, having a height of `56.9055pt` (2cm) and depth of `0.0`.
- The page body, occupying a height of `170.71654pt` (6cm) and depth of `1.94444pt` on the first page (this comes from the `j` and `g`s on the last line), and `0.0` on the second.
- A `\lineskip` glue of `1pt`.
- The footer, occupying a height of `56.9055` (2cm) and depth of `0.0`.

From this we can see two things:

- By trying to have the page body be immediately followed by the footer box, you're ending up with a `\lineskip` glue being inserted. If you don't want that, you can either decrease `\lineskiplimit` sufficiently (here, to a value lower than about 1.65cm ≈ 46.85pt), or set `\lineskip` to `0pt`.
- You also need to account for the *depth* of the page body, namely (in simple cases) that of the last line of text.

A solution that seems to work for both of them is to start your footer by accounting for `\prevdepth` (and `\lineskip`). By adding `\vskip-\prevdepth \vskip-\lineskip \vskip 10pt` and correspondingly `\advance\vsize by -10pt` to your document, one gets:

[image: revised]

which is consistent and seems to be what you want.

By the way the `\nointerlineskip` at the *end* of the footer doesn't do anything and can be removed; it is equivalent to `\prevdepth=-1000pt` and only works to suppress the *next* interline glue. (Putting it at the beginning will suppress the `\lineskip` glue but won't do anything about the difference in depths.)

**Edit:** Another solution is to allow the natural `\baselineskip` to come into play. Change your `\makefootline` from a `\vbox` to a `\vtop` so that the right `\baselineskip` glue gets used automatically (`10.05556pt` for the first page, and `12pt` for the second), and also account for this with `\advance\vsize by -\baselineskip`. The result is the same as shown in the image above.

**Edit 2**: Is the “footline 3” clipped in the screenshot above, or is it just resting on the baseline? Look at a close-up:

[image: close-up]

The fact is, some characters (like the “o”, “t”, “e” and “3” above) are defined in the font to have some pixels beyond their stated depth. So although `\hbox{Footline 3}` has a depth of 0.0 as far as TeX knows (unlike something like `\hbox{Footline 3 gg}`, which has a depth of `1.94444pt`), in fact the font designer (in this case Knuth, for Computer Modern) has chosen to blacken a few more pixels. This is another reason one generally doesn't try to use all available area on the page in this way.

Comment: But "footline 3" still seems to be clipped at the bottom in your screen shot.

Comment: The problem with setting the baselineskip is, that I define the vheight at the beginning. Whenever someone changes the fontsize on the page, the baselineskip may change, too. And then the compensation of the vheight does not match the baselineskip glue at the end of a page.

Comment: @ceving Then you can use the other method. What is your reason for doing something so strange BTW (why do you need text to occupy all available area on the PDF page)?

Comment: I just want to position the foot line exactly at the bottom of the page, because I need to draw a vertical line, which ends exactly a the bottom of the page.